# indexOutofRangeException occurred

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I am getting 'indexOutofRangeException occurred' error - 'FixedActual'

this is the code i am using any help would be appropriated.

```
SqlDataReader dataReader = null;
SqlCommand Scmd = new SqlCommand("SalesGetRecalcOrderItemCosts", this._connection);
Scmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
Scmd.Transaction = currentTransaction;
Scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNumber", ItemSODBOM.SONO); //SoItem.fSnoNo
Scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UTCompFCostRef", sUTCompFCostRef);//utcomp.fcostref
Scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UTCompFCostEst", sUTCompFCostEst);//utcomp.fcostest
Scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UTCompFCostMType", sUTCompFCostMType);//utcomp.fcostmtype
Scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderItemNumber", finumber); //SoItem.finumber
Scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderType", "S");//Sales Order
Scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UseStandardTransitCost", "0");
Scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GetExtendedCosts", "0");
dataReader = Scmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dataReader.Read())
{
    using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand updateCommand = this._connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        string sql = @"
        UPDATE SOITEM SET 
        FFIXACT = @FixedActual, FLABACT = @LaborActual, FMATLACT = @MaterialActual,
        FOTHRACT = @OtherActual, FOVHDACT= @OverheadActual, FRTGSETUPA= @SetupActual,
        FSUBACT = @SubcontractActual, FTOOLACT = @ToolActual,FSTANDPART = 0,
        FTOTPTIME = @TotalPTime, FTOTSTIME = @TotalSTime, FULABCOST1 = @ULaborCost1  
        WHERE FSONO = @FSONO and FINUMBER = @FINUM  
                                        ";
        updateCommand.CommandText = sql;
        updateCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        updateCommand.Transaction = currentTransaction;
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FixedActual", dataReader["FixedActual"]); //This is where i am getting error
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LaborActual", dataReader["LaborActual"]);
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MaterialActual", dataReader["MaterialActual"]);
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OtherActual", dataReader["OtherActual"]);
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OverheadActual", dataReader["OverheadActual"]);
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SetupActual", dataReader["SetupActual"]);
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubcontractActual", dataReader["SubcontractActual"]);
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ToolActual", dataReader["ToolActual"]);
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalPTime", dataReader["TotalPTime"]);
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalSTime", dataReader["TotalSTime"]);
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ULaborCost1", dataReader["ULaborCost1"]);
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FSONO", ItemSODBOM.SONO);
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FINUM", finumber);
        updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

}
```

Comment: Need more information. Which line is the exception occuring on? What have you tried to fix it?

Comment: out of curiosity, what are you trying to do here? you're executing a SPROC, reading the results, then passing those results to an UPDATE command? Why do 2 round-trips? Why not just do your UPDATE in the SPROC itself? In regards to the error, did you `debug` the results of the SPROC? Does "FixedActual" exist in the data reader??

Comment: Are you sure your stored procedure returns a FixedActual field?

Comment: I got it, actually it should returns that value but unfortunately it is retuning some error. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the exception means your `SqlDataReader` doesn't have a `FixedActual` column. That's all we can really tell from what you've shown, to be honest. We don't know what your `SalesGetRecalcOrderItemCosts` stored procedure does, but it appears not to be returning exactly what you expect.

You might want to look at the `SqlDataReader` in a debugger and see what fields *are* available.

(As an aside, you should be using `using` statements for these resources - the command, reader etc - so that you dispose of everything properly. It's also not clear why you're using fully-qualified type names in some places but not others.)